# GoJS Pipe Example Add TextBlock

Tags: javascript, typescript, gojs

It is not apparent to me how to edit the [GoJS Pipes example here](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/pipes.html) so that I can display text within the "pipes" without messing up the layout. I am trying to apply [the answer to the same question given here](https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-add-text-in-a-node-in-the-example-pipe/7352/2) but it's so old that it could be out of date, or maybe it's just not explicit enough for me to make sense of it properly with my limited knowledge of this lib.

I have started a hardcoded pipeline that looks like so:

[image]

The pipeline code:

```js
const base = 15;
const minLen = base * 2;
const maxLen = base * 6;

const minInc1 = minLen + base;
const minInc2 = minLen * 2;
const minInc3 = minLen + (base * 3);

interface IShapeParams {
    angle?: number
    text?: string
    key: number
}

const createShapeI = (params: IShapeParams): ObjectData => ({
    geo: `F1 M0 0 L${minLen} 0 ${minLen} ${maxLen} 0 ${maxLen}z`,
    ports: [
        { id: "U1", spot: "0.5 0 0 0.5" },
        { id: "U2", spot: "0.5 1 0 -0.5" }
    ],
    ...params
});


const startHorz = 0;
const startVert = 0;

export const pipeline = {
    "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
    "copiesArrays": true,
    "copiesArrayObjects": true,
    "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fid",
    "linkToPortIdProperty": "tid",
    "nodeDataArray": [
        {
            ...createShapeI({ key: 1, text: "Pipe 1", angle: 90 }),
            "loc": `${startHorz} ${startVert}`
        },
        {
            ...createShapeI({ key: 2, text: "Pipe 2", angle: 90 }),
            "loc": `${startHorz - maxLen} ${startVert}`
        }
    ],
    "linkDataArray": [
        { "from": 1, "to": 2, "fid": "U2", "tid": "U1" }
    ]
};
```

The original `nodeTemplate` from the Pipe source code:

```js
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Spot",
            {
                locationObjectName: "SHAPE",
                locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
                selectionAdorned: false,  // use a Binding on the Shape.stroke to show selection
                itemTemplate:
                // each port is an "X" shape whose alignment spot and port ID are given by the item data
                    $(go.Panel,
                        new go.Binding("portId", "id"),
                        new go.Binding("alignment", "spot", go.Spot.parse),
                        $(go.Shape, "XLine",
                            { width: 6, height: 6, background: "transparent", fill: null, stroke: "gray" },
                            new go.Binding("figure", "id", portFigure),  // portFigure converter is defined below
                            new go.Binding("angle", "angle"))
                    ),
                // hide a port when it is connected
                linkConnected: (node, link, port) => {
                    if (link.category === "") {
                        port.visible = false;
                    }
                },
                linkDisconnected: (node, link, port) => {
                    if (link.category === "") {
                        port.visible = true;
                    }
                }
            },
            // this creates the variable number of ports for this Spot Panel, based on the data
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "ports"),
            // remember the location of this Node
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // remember the angle of this Node
            new go.Binding("angle", "angle").makeTwoWay(),
            // move a selected part into the Foreground layer, so it isn't obscured by any non-selected parts
            new go.Binding("layerName", "isSelected", function(s) {
                return s ? "Foreground" : "";
            }).ofObject(),
            $(go.Shape,
                {
                    name: "SHAPE",
                    // the following are default values;
                    // actual values may come from the node data object via data binding
                    geometryString: "F1 M0 0 L20 0 20 20 0 20 z",
                    fill: "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)"
                },
                // this determines the actual shape of the Shape
                new go.Binding("geometryString", "geo"),
                // selection causes the stroke to be blue instead of black
                new go.Binding("stroke", "isSelected", (s) => {
                    return s ? "dodgerblue" : "black";
                }).ofObject())
        );
```

Now when I try to apply the [solution given on the referenced thread](https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-add-text-in-a-node-in-the-example-pipe/7352/2) I end up with the `nodeTemplate` like so:

```js
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Spot",
            {
                locationObjectName: "SHAPE",
                locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
                selectionAdorned: false,  // use a Binding on the Shape.stroke to show selection
                // hide a port when it is connected
                linkConnected: (node, link, port) => {
                    if (link.category === "") {
                        port.visible = false;
                    }
                },
                linkDisconnected: (node, link, port) => {
                    if (link.category === "") {
                        port.visible = true;
                    }
                }
            },
            $(go.Panel, "Spot",
                {
                    itemTemplate:
                    // each port is an "X" shape whose alignment spot and port ID are given by the item data
                        $(go.Panel,
                            new go.Binding("portId", "id"),
                            new go.Binding("alignment", "spot", go.Spot.parse),
                            $(go.Shape, "XLine",
                                { width: 6, height: 6, background: "transparent", fill: null, stroke: "gray" },
                                new go.Binding("figure", "id", portFigure),  // portFigure converter is defined below
                                new go.Binding("angle", "angle"))
                        )
                },
                // this creates the variable number of ports for this Spot Panel, based on the data
                new go.Binding("itemArray", "ports"),
                // remember the location of this Node
                new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
                // remember the angle of this Node
                new go.Binding("angle", "angle").makeTwoWay(),
                // move a selected part into the Foreground layer, so it isn't obscured by any non-selected parts
                new go.Binding("layerName", "isSelected", function(s) {
                    return s ? "Foreground" : "";
                }).ofObject(),
                $(go.Shape,
                    {
                        name: "SHAPE",
                        // the following are default values;
                        // actual values may come from the node data object via data binding
                        geometryString: "F1 M0 0 L20 0 20 20 0 20 z",
                        fill: "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)"
                    },
                    // this determines the actual shape of the Shape
                    new go.Binding("geometryString", "geo"),
                    // selection causes the stroke to be blue instead of black
                    new go.Binding("stroke", "isSelected", (s) => {
                        return s ? "dodgerblue" : "black";
                    }).ofObject())
            ),
            $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 5 }, new go.Binding("text", "text"))
        );
```

This renders the text correctly, but it completely breaks the layout as the ports have switched sides, I have no idea why. On top of that, the space seen in between the pipes now I cannot reconcile at all by trying to alter the `loc` strings on the pipeline, in fact nothing I do to the `loc` properties does anything at all now. See below image:

[image]

How can I just add text blocks to these shapes while keeping the same layout and functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the pipe template is currently structured like this:

```
Node (that is a Spot Panel)
 - 1st child: Shape
 - 2nd-nth child: Item array of x's
```

Spot panels have one main element (usually the first child unless you specify it), and then N other elements that are positioned based on it. So at the very minimum you want a structure like this:

```
Node (that is a Spot Panel)
 - 1st child: Panel (another Spot panel)
    - Shape
    - TextBlock
 - 2nd-nth child: Item array of x's
```

So you are swapping out the Shape for a Panel (a container with lots of stuff) that will contain that shape. This will work as long as that Panel is exactly the same size as the shape it would be replacing. If its larger, for instance if the text is larger than the shape, then you're in trouble.

How to solve that problem really depends on what you want the result to look like. The simplest way would be to force the TextBlock to `stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill`, so that it always sizes itself identical to the shape, so that the Panel (Shape+TextBlock) is always identical in size to the Shape it replaced.

Separately you probably want the TextBlock, which will assume the entire area of the gray shape, to be centered vertically, so you'd want to add `verticalAlignment: go.Spot.Center`

Like this:

```
      myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Spot",
          {
            locationObjectName: "SHAPE",
            locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
            selectionAdorned: false,  // use a Binding on the Shape.stroke to show selection
            itemTemplate:
              // each port is an "X" shape whose alignment spot and port ID are given by the item data
              $(go.Panel,
                new go.Binding("portId", "id"),
                new go.Binding("alignment", "spot", go.Spot.parse),
                $(go.Shape, "XLine",
                  { width: 6, height: 6, background: "transparent", fill: null, stroke: "gray" },
                  new go.Binding("figure", "id", portFigure),  // portFigure converter is defined below
                  new go.Binding("angle", "angle"))
              ),
            // hide a port when it is connected
            linkConnected: function(node, link, port) {
              if (link.category === "") port.visible = false;
            },
            linkDisconnected: function(node, link, port) {
              if (link.category === "") port.visible = true;
            }
          },
          // this creates the variable number of ports for this Spot Panel, based on the data
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "ports"),
          // remember the location of this Node
          new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
          // remember the angle of this Node
          new go.Binding("angle", "angle").makeTwoWay(),
          // move a selected part into the Foreground layer, so it isn't obscured by any non-selected parts
          new go.Binding("layerName", "isSelected", function(s) { return s ? "Foreground" : ""; }).ofObject(),
          // Everything except the ports: (the pipe body, and pipe text)
          $(go.Panel, "Spot",
            $(go.Shape,
              {
                name: "SHAPE",
                // the following are default values;
                // actual values may come from the node data object via data binding
                geometryString: "F1 M0 0 L20 0 20 20 0 20 z",
                fill: "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)"
              },
              // this determines the actual shape of the Shape
              new go.Binding("geometryString", "geo"),
              // selection causes the stroke to be blue instead of black
              new go.Binding("stroke", "isSelected", function(s) { return s ? "dodgerblue" : "black"; }).ofObject()),
            $(go.TextBlock, "Some text")
          )
        );
```

Here is that modification live: https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/RwrKqrq?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you! This was enough to get me in the right direction, I was way off haha